# Class 'Mage_Googlecheckout_Helper_Data' not found

Tags: php, magento

We've just upgraded from Magento version 1.8.0.0 to 1.8.1.0 and now when we go to the configuration section of our site we receive the message:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Googlecheckout_Helper_Data' not found in /home/dir/public_html/guides/setup/app/Mage.php on line 547
```

Any ideas on what might be causing this

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Please check the releasenotes:

> 1. Close the Admin Panel browser window.
> 2. As a user with root privileges, delete all files except config.xml from the following >directory:
>      magento-install-dir/app/code/core/Mage/GoogleCheckout/etc
> 3. When you log back in to the Admin Panel, everything works as expected.
>      If you're still encountering errors, see Getting Help With Your Installation or Upgrade.

-- [Magento Community Edition (CE) Release Notes (1.8 and later)](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce-18-later-release-notes#11810-changes-upgrade-issue)

Comment: Perfect a gem solution.

Comment: Worked on my client who uses magento v1.9.2.1

Comment: Awesome! Worked instantly! haha :D Just upgrade to 1.9.2.2 from 1.7 and countered this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution. :)

Answer (score 7):

If you get this error it means you are on the right track.

> Solution:
>
> Close the Admin Panel browser window. As a user with root privileges,
>   delete all files except config.xml from the following directory:
>   magento-install-dir/app/code/core/Mage/GoogleCheckout/etc When you log
>   back in to the Admin Panel, everything works as expected. If you're
>   still encountering errors, see Getting Help With Your Installation or
>   Upgrade.

The error you get was predicted and documented by the Magento core team. The solution I gave is from the [Magento 1.8.1.0 release notes page](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce-18-later-release-notes)

Comment: The perfect solution for me - worked flawlessly. Thank you @Marius

Answer (score 4):

Oddly I recently got this on a Magento 1.9.2.3 install.

The cause is the following missing from the app\code\core\Mage\GoogleCheckout\etc\config.xml

```
<global>
...
    <helpers>
        <googlecheckout>
            <class>Mage_GoogleCheckout_Helper</class>
        </googlecheckout>
    </helpers>
...
</global>
```

Results in the autoloader not being able to find the helper file hence reverting to checking for Mage_Googlecheckout.

Answer (score 3):

- Delete all files except `config.xml` from `/app/code/core/Mage/GoogleCheckout/etc`.
- Clear the cache.

Comment: maybe this will help, but it does not answer the question: `Any ideas on what might be causing this`

Answer (score 1):

I agree the solution above works. However, I got this error myself after upgrading from Magento 1.7 to 1.8 simply by copying all the new files over the old Magento 1.7 filesystem. I fixed this (and perhaps other bugs waiting) by removing all contents of the app/code/core folder and copying all files from the fresh Magento 1.8 folder app/code/core/* (Mage and Zend) to the now empty folder. Same thing, different approach.

Answer (score 1):

Every of the answer so far seem dirty to me. Instead of crippeling the Mage_GoogleCheckout Module you should just deactivate it.

Following steps will result in deactivating the module and leaving the code intact:

1. go to app/etc/modules
2. edit Mage_All.xml
3. search for `<Mage_GoogleCheckout>`
4. place `<!--` in front of `<Mage_GoogleCheckout>` and `-->` right after `</Mage_GoogleCheckout>`
5. save the file
6. if the problem still persists refresh cache (go back in your browser until you see the adminhtml again, go to system -> cache-management and click the two red buttons in the top right corner)

Answer (score 1):

Go to the folder app/etc/modules/Mage_All.xml

Set false for module.

```
   <Mage_GoogleCheckout>
        <active>false</active>
        <codePool>core</codePool>
        <depends>
            <Mage_Sales/>
            <Mage_Payment/>
            <Mage_Usa/>
        </depends>
    </Mage_GoogleCheckout>
```

Comment: Technically this will make the error stop occurring, but that will have the effect of disabling Google checkout. The correct answer is the answer about the missing step from the release notes.

Answer (score 0):

If you will delete files then google checkout will not work.

I found this answer useful.

```
<helpers>
        <googlecheckout>
            <class>Mage_GoogleCheckout_Helper</class>
        </googlecheckout>
    </helpers>
```