# Magento: Check if product is already in cart

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, magento, product

Using magento for my shopping cart system. I have mini cart on top menu, when I added product it will show product title with price in mini cart.  Currently have product quantity edit link but I need quantity box in mini cart to update quantity with ajax. I have followed this link http://ceckoslab.com/magento/magento-check-if-product-is-in-cart/, but getting following error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Smartview_Helper_Data' not found in /app/Mage.php on line 547
```

can anyone help me to resolve above error ?

Answer (score 1):

When Magento is trying to look to `Mage_Somemodule_` instead of your own module, it does means that it did not found your own file or your own module.

Three possible reasons :

1. Your module is not recognized at all, maybe something is wrong in your module definition
2. Something is wrong/mistyped in your config.xml
3. Something is wrong/mistyped in your class name

Be sure you have everything right from the tutorial and/or copy paste your code here so we can help further

In this case the two xml are wrong in the way that it should not ignore case sensitivity

CeckosLab_SmartView.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <CeckosLab_SmartView>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </CeckosLab_SmartView >
    </modules>
</config>
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <CeckosLab_SmartView>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </CeckosLab_SmartView>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <smartview>
                <class>CeckosLab_SmartView_Helper</class>
            </smartview>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: hi, thank you. you can go-through this link http://ceckoslab.com/magento/magento-check-if-product-is-in-cart/ then you will see all the code which i have tried

Comment: @RubanKutty well, obviously not, since the writer of the post is saying it work when it doesn't for you. You may have mistyped/misplaced something. Check it again.

Comment: thank you @b.enoit.be its working charm now :) can i make that function in ajax ? can you help me ?

Comment: @RubanKutty This is really a broad question to answer. Maybe have a look at this resource http://blog.magikcommerce.com/how-to-use-ajax-in-your-magento-modules-themes/ and if you have problems when implementing it, stack overflow is still there ;) In the meantime, consider accepting this answer as the good one, and also doing the same on your other questions for answers helping you out :)

Answer (score 0):

please check it the Answer of stackoverflow 
[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569358/class-mage-googlecheckout-helper-data-not-found)
In this link check this answer with 20 votes
Please check the releasenotes:
It will help you guide how to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

If your helper error contains Mage_ before your module, it means your helper is either not defined or defined incorrectly in your module's xml or you are calling it incorrectly.

If it is defined correctly this should work:

`Mage::helper('smartview')->doSomething();`

or try:

`Mage::helper('ceckoslab_smartview')->doSomething();`

Also, make sure you clear the cache as xml is cached heavily.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Make enrty in config.xml

```
<global>
......
<helpers>
    <test>
        <class>Module_Test_Helper</class>
    </test>
</helpers>
......
</global>
```

Create a Data.php file inside Helper folder and write following code

```
<?php
class Module_Test_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

Thats it you need to do now if you call this code it will not throw any error:

```
<?php Mage::helper("test")->actionname(); ?>
```